# Undefined reference - calling 2 strings into a function

Tags: c++, string, function

My question is: Why does my `changepassage (passage,word);` function located in `main()` give me an error for "no matching function"?

my code is supposed to pass in strings titled `passage` and `word` from `main()` to a function `void changepassage(string passage,string word)`.  What I'm trying to do with `changepassage()` is turn the string `passage ="..."` into string `word` (I'm still working on removing commas and periods) with each word from the `passage` assigned it's own element.

```cpp
//Function prototypes
void changepassage (string,string&);

int main() 
{
  const string passage = "...";

  string word[200];
  
  changepassage(passage,word);
}
```

This function `changepassage()` is being labeled as "not matching function" when I try and run the code, but I don't see what the issue is.

The reason I want to make this new string with `word` is because I want to make another function that will go through the string and tell me how many times each `word` in an entire `passage` occurs.

```cpp
void changepassage (string passage,string word) 
{
  string temp;
  int s = 0;
  
  int plength = passage.length();
  string store[plength];
  

  for (int a = 0; a < plength; a++) 
  {
    if ((isalpha(passage[a]))  || (passage[a] !=' ' && passage[a] !='.' && passage[a] !=',' && passage[a] !=';')) 
    {
      temp += passage[a];
      
    }
    else if (ispunct(passage[a]) || isspace(passage[a])) 
    {
      word[s] = temp[s];
      
      s++;
      
      temp = '\0';
    }
  }  
  
  
  //for (int s = 0; s < 188; s++) 
  //{
  //  cout << store[s] << endl;  
  //}
}
```

Comment: `void changepassage (string,string&);` and `void changepassage (string passage,string word)` in the definition the second parameter isn't a reference (i.e. no `&`)

Comment: @Christian This call of the function changepassage(passage,word); is wrong. The second argument has the type string  *.

Comment: Good catch on the array of 200 string @VladfromMoscow

Answer (score 1):

Your function's declaration does not match its definition:

```cpp
void changepassage (string,string&);
```

```cpp
void changepassage (string passage,string word)
```

See the difference?  In the declaration, the 2nd parameter is taking a `string` **by reference**, but in the definition it is taking a `string` **by value** instead.  You need to fix the definition to also pass by reference.

And then, in `main()`, the `word` variable being passed in to that 2nd parameter does not match the declaration of that parameter, which is why you are getting a "no matching function" error.  `word` is a `string[200]` array, not a single `string` (or a `string&` reference):

```cpp
string word[200];
changepassage(passage,word);
```

You need to drop the `[200]`:

```cpp
string word;
changepassage(passage,word);
```

Also, inside the function itself, you have a `store` variable:

```cpp
int plength = passage.length();
string store[plength];
```

Aside from the fact that such array syntax is [non-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/), you probably don't actually want an *array* holding `plength` number of strings, but rather a single `string` whose *length* can hold `plength` number of characters.  But even so, you are not actually saving anything into `store`, so you should just get rid of it altogether.

You are also writing `char`s to `word` when it does not have space to hold them.  You are not pre-sizing the `word` ahead of time, so use of the `[]` operator is *undefined behavior*.  You should use the string's `+=` operator or `push_back()` method instead:

```cpp
word += temp[s];
```

```cpp
word.push_back(temp[s]);
```

But, to be honest, I don't really know what your function is trying to do.  It is a jumbled mess of nonsense and should be rewritten from scratch.

---

**UPDATE**: based on a comment you added:

> I'm trying to assign each word in the passage to its own element in an array

You need to re-write this function.  Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

size_t changepassage (const string&, string(&)[200]);

int main() 
{
  const string passage = "...";
  string words[200];
  
  size_t count = changepassage(passage, words);
  for (size_t s = 0; s < count; ++s)
  {
    cout << words[s] << endl;  
  }
}

size_t changepassage (const string& passage, string (&words)[200]) 
{
  if (passage.empty())
    return 0;

  string temp;
  size_t s = 0;
  string::size_type plength = passage.size();

  for (string::size_type a = 0; a < plength; ++a)
  {
    if (isalpha(passage[a]) || (passage[a] != ' ' && passage[a] != '.' && passage[a] != ',' && passage[a] != ';'))
    {
      temp += passage[a];
    }
    else if (ispunct(passage[a]) || isspace(passage[a])) 
    {
      words[s] = temp;
      if (++s == 200) return s;
      temp = "";
    }
  }  
  
  if (!temp.empty() && s < 200)
  {
    words[s] = temp;
    ++s;
  }

  return s;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

size_t changepassage (const string&, string*, size_t);

int main() 
{
  const string passage = "...";
  string words[200];
  
  size_t count = changepassage(passage, words, 200);
  for (size_t s = 0; s < count; ++s)
  {
    cout << words[s] << endl;  
  }
}

size_t changepassage (const string& passage, string *words, size_t max_words) 
{
  if (passage.empty() || !words || max_words == 0)
    return 0;

  string temp;
  size_t s = 0;
  string::size_type plength = passage.size();

  for (string::size_type a = 0; a < plength; ++a)
  {
    if (isalpha(passage[a]) || (passage[a] != ' ' && passage[a] != '.' && passage[a] != ',' && passage[a] != ';'))
    {
      temp += passage[a];
    }
    else if (ispunct(passage[a]) || isspace(passage[a])) 
    {
      words[s] = temp;
      if (++s == max_words) return s;
      temp = "";
    }
  }  
  
  if (!temp.empty() && s < max_words)
  {
    words[s] = temp;
    ++s;
  }

  return s;
}
```

Or, if your instructor will allow it, use `std::vector` instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void changepassage (const string&, vector<string>&);

int main() 
{
  const string passage = "...";
  vector<string> words;
  
  changepassage(passage, words);

  for (const auto& s : words) 
  {
    cout << s << endl;
  }
}

void changepassage (const string& passage, vector<string>& words)
{
  string temp;  
  string::size_type plength = passage.size();

  for (int a = 0; a < plength; ++a)
  {
    if (isalpha(passage[a]) || (passage[a] != ' ' && passage[a] != '.' && passage[a] != ',' && passage[a] != ';')) 
    {
      temp += passage[a];
    }
    else if (ispunct(passage[a]) || isspace(passage[a]))
    {
      words.push_back(temp);
      temp = "";
    }
  }  

  if (!temp.empty())
    words.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you.  My instructor suggested I use the [200] so I assumed it needed to stay in.  Though I'm trying to assign each word in the passage to its own element in an array but I'm thinking of just starting from scratch because before I was outputting the words in their own elements but they were stuck in the function and now (after the changes) it's printing out the diamonds with a ? symbol.

Comment: "*My instructor suggested I use the [200]*" - Then either your instructor gave you bad advice, or you misunderstood what was actually being told to you. "*I'm trying to assign each word in the passage to its own element in an array*" - that would have been good info to provide up front, you did not make that clear enough in your original question. That is not what this code is actually doing, in which case, yes the code definately needs some rewriting to accomplish that properly.